# Destination resolver returned non-existent partition

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using Spring-Kafka to consume messages from Confluent Kafka and I am using RetryTopicConfiguration Bean to configure the topics and backoff strategy. My application works fine but I see a lot of WARNING log like the one below in my logs and I am wondering if my configuration is incorrect.

```
DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory$1 : Destination resolver returned non-existent partition flow-events-retry-0-4, KafkaProducer will determine partition to use for this topic
```

Config Code

```
@Bean
    public KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTopicConfiguration myRetryableTopic(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .exponentialBackoff(BACKOFF_INITIAL_DELAY_10MINS, BACKOFF_EXPONENTIAL_MULTIPLIER_3, BACKOFF_MAX_DELAY_4HRS)
                .maxAttempts(5)
                .doNotAutoCreateRetryTopics()
                .setTopicSuffixingStrategy(TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
                .create(template);
    }
```

The retry topics are created separately with 1 partition and replication factor of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the same partition as the original topic is used; you can override that behavior by overriding the `DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory` `@Bean`:

```java
@Bean(RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.DEAD_LETTER_PUBLISHING_RECOVERER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory factory(DestinationTopicResolver resolver) {
    DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory factory = new DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory(resolver) {

        @Override
        protected TopicPartition resolveTopicPartition(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr, DestinationTopic nextDestination) {
            return new TopicPartition(nextDestination.getDestinationName(), -1); // Kafka Chooses
//          return new TopicPartition(nextDestination.getDestinationName(), 0);  // explict
        }

    };
    factory.setDeadLetterPublishingRecovererCustomizer(dlpr -> {
        // ...
    });
    return factory;
}
```

As you can see in this example, you can also customize DLPR properties here too.

```java
/**
 * Creates and returns the {@link TopicPartition}, where the original record should be forwarded.
 * By default, it will use the partition same as original record's partition, in the next destination topic.
 *
 * <p>{@link DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer#checkPartition} has logic to check whether that partition exists,
 * and if it doesn't it sets -1, to allow the Producer itself to assign a partition to the record.</p>
 *
 * <p>Subclasses can inherit from this method to override the implementation, if necessary.</p>
 *
 * @param cr The original {@link ConsumerRecord}, which is to be forwarded to DLT
 * @param nextDestination The next {@link DestinationTopic}, where the consumerRecord is to be forwarded
 * @return An instance of {@link TopicPartition}, specifying the topic and partition, where the cr is to be sent
 */
protected TopicPartition resolveTopicPartition(final ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr, final DestinationTopic nextDestination) {
    return new TopicPartition(nextDestination.getDestinationName(), cr.partition());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary. This makes sense. I will try this out.

Comment: Hi Gary, I've tried to implement your answer but I'm getting this error saying that DestinationTopicResolver bean could not be found.

Comment: Please ask a new question showing your code and configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell In `spring-kafka 3.0.6`, if `-1` is used how does the producer assign a partition to the record? Will it use the same key that was used to publish the original topic?

Comment: See the javadocs for the default assignor:  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_partition.assignment.strategies.