# RetrayableTopic - Let Kafka chose retry/dlt partition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

By default, Spring Kafka's retryable topic sends messages from the main topic to the retry/DLT on the same partition as the original ConsumerRecord.

However, in my case, I have a different number of partitions configured between the main topic, retry topic, and DLT. I know that when a partition doesn't exist, the destination resolver lets Kafka choose it.

Instead, I would like Kafka to always choose the partition.

I've seen this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70836041/7612074) that seems to be exactly what I need.
I'm using **spring-kafka 2.7.12** with the following configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public RetryTopicConfiguration retryTopicConfiguration(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .maxAttempts(3)
                .useSingleTopicForFixedDelays()
                .fixedBackOff(3000)
                .dltHandlerMethod(DltHandler.class, "handle")
                .retryOn(List.of(ProcessRetryableException.class, RuntimeException.class))
                .retryTopicSuffix(".RETRY")
                .dltSuffix(".DLT")
                .create(template);
    }
}
```

And as suggested in the previous answer, i added the following bean declaration

```java
@Bean(RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.DEAD_LETTER_PUBLISHING_RECOVERER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
public DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory(DestinationTopicResolver resolver) {
    return new DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory(resolver) {
        @Override
        protected TopicPartition resolveTopicPartition(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr, DestinationTopic nextDestination) {
            return new TopicPartition(nextDestination.getDestinationName(), -1); // Kafka Chooses
        }
    };
}
```

Unfortunately, the application won't start up because it cannot find any **DestinationTopicResolver** bean in the spring context.

I'm unable to create it manually since the autoconfiguration injects two maps into it, containing essential information about the topics (used for determining the next destination topic in the retry flow), and I would lose all this information.

It doesn't seem to be a spring bean but a simple bean referenced in the DestinationTopicResolver

What am i missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: 2.7.x is no longer supported; advanced configuration was completely overhauled in 2.9.x due to severe limitations in previous implementations (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-config). Please upgrade to 2.9.12 or later and use the new configuration model; if you still have problems, post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gary Russel pointed out, it was a limitation of that version

Solved upgrading to 2.9.12 and adding this to my configuration class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig extends RetryTopicConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public RetryTopicConfiguration retryTopicConfiguration(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .maxAttempts(3)
                .useSingleTopicForFixedDelays()
                .fixedBackOff(3000)
                .dltHandlerMethod("dltProcessor", "process")
                .retryOn(List.of(ProcessRetryableException.class, RuntimeException.class))
                .retryTopicSuffix(".RETRY")
                .dltSuffix(".DLT")
                .create(template);
    }

    @Override
    public RetryTopicComponentFactory createComponentFactory() {

        return new RetryTopicComponentFactory() {

            @Override
            public DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory(DestinationTopicResolver destinationTopicResolver) {

                return new DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory(destinationTopicResolver) {

                    @Override
                    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer create() {
                        super.neverLogListenerException();
                        return super.create();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected TopicPartition resolveTopicPartition(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr, DestinationTopic nextDestination) {
                        return new TopicPartition(nextDestination.getDestinationName(), -1); // Kafka Chooses
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```